# Insert after checking a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this but it shows an error **#1064**

```
  if ((SELECT count(*) FROM group_participants WHERE collegeID = 1 AND itemID = 1) < 9)
  begin
  INSERT INTO group_participants (collegeID, partID, itemID) VALUES (1, 20 , 2)  
  end
```

Full error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if ((SELECT count(*) FROM group_participants WHERE collegeID = 1 AND itemID = 1)' at line 1

Comment: Post entire error message please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support `if` except in programming blocks.  You can express this as:

```
INSERT INTO group_participants (collegeID, partID, itemID) 
    SELECT 1, 20 , 2 
    FROM dual
    WHERE (SELECT count(*)
           FROM group_participants
           WHERE collegeID = 1 AND itemID = 1
          ) < 9;
```

It is curious that the `itemID` being inserted is not the same as the one being tested.  I imagine that these should be the same.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7

Comment: Ya, the itemID should have been the same. but it's showing the above error.